# Texture is single color

Tags: texturing

I can't apply a texture to this heart shape. It was an SVG and I made a mesh out of it, but the texture is a solid color. The texture on the chain is applied correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: here: https://pasteall.org/blend/2a5e70373bf447279843bfe8ff437997 @moonboots

Comment: What kind of texture are your trying to apply? for the moment the Principled BSDF has its Metallic value at 1, which makes it reflect the world. If you plan to project an Image Texture you need to unwrap it correctly, for the moment the UV island is stretched and tiny

Comment: I'm trying to apply the silver material in the file. It looks good on the chain, but on the heart I have only solid color and no metallic effect.

Comment: You shared the file but you didn't pack the image you use as HDRI, so it's hard to see the same thing as you, maybe pack it and share again

Comment: I'm using forest.exr that comes with blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, it's just that there's a large light in front of your object and it reflects it. You can remove it, or reduce its size, or disable its visibility in the *Object* panel.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you!